# Change bazel output symlink location

Tags: c++, bazel

I am using Bazel as my C++ build system and whenever I build my project my root directory is cluttered up with the bazel symlinks: `bazel-bin`, `bazel-out`, `bazel-pipeline`, and `bazel-testlogs`. Is it possible for me to have bazel place these in a directory such as `./out`? I have tried using `--output_base=./out` and `--output_user_root=./out` however the symlinks are still placed in the root directory.

Here is what I want my project structure to be after a `bazel [options] build`:

```
ProjectRoot
├── bin
│   ├── App.cpp
│   └── BUILD.bazel
├── lib
│   ├── Lib1
│   │   ├── Lib1.cpp
│   │   ├── Lib1.hpp
│   │   └── BUILD.bazel
│   ├── Lib2
│   │   ├── Lib2.cpp
│   │   ├── Lib2.hpp
│   │   └── BUILD.bazel
│   └── BUILD.bazel
├── out
│   ├── bazel-bin
│   │   ├── stuff
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── bazel-out
│   │   ├── stuff
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── bazel-pipeline
│   │   ├── stuff
│   │   └── ...
│   └── bazel-testlogs
│       ├── stuff
│       └── ...
├── test
│   ├── test.cpp
│   └── BUILD.bazel
└── WORKSPACE.bazel
```

Here is what it currently is:

```
ProjectRoot
├── bazel-bin
│   ├── stuff
│   └── ...
├── bazel-out
│   ├── stuff
│   └── ...
├── bazel-pipeline
│   ├── stuff
│   └── ...
├── bazel-testlogs
│   ├── stuff
│   └── ...
├── bin
│   ├── App.cpp
│   └── BUILD.bazel
├── lib
│   ├── Lib1
│   │   ├── Lib1.cpp
│   │   ├── Lib1.hpp
│   │   ├── BUILD.bazel
│   ├── Lib2
│   │   ├── Lib2.cpp
│   │   ├── Lib2.hpp
│   │   ├── BUILD.bazel
│   └── BUILD.bazel
├── out
├── test
│   ├── test.cpp
│   └── BUILD.bazel
└── WORKSPACE.bazel
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`--symlink_prefix`](https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--symlink_prefix). E.g., `--symlink_prefix=/tmp/anywhere/you/want/bazel-`.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I was looking for! `bazel build --symlink_prefix=./out/bazel //app:main` gave me exactly the structure I was looking for. Thanks!